# Map JSON object to class in Azure Function API Request class parameter

Tags: c#, arrays, api, asp.net-core, json.net

Map JSON object to class c# property
Use case :
I am creating API in Azure Function and passing parameter-ReservationDraftRequestDto class like below code

[FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] **ReservationDraftRequestDto reservationDraftRequestDto**,
            ILogger log)
        {
        }

DTO class:

API URI: http://localhost:7071/api/Function1 
JSON-for calling API is:
{
    "SoftHoldIDs": 444,
    "AppliedUsages": [
        {
            "SoftHoldID": 444,
            "UsageYearID": 4343,
            "DaysApplied": 0,
            "PointsApplied": 1
        }
    ],
    "Guests": [
        1,
        2
    ]
}

```
public class ReservationDraftRequestDto
{

    public int SoftHoldIDs { get; set; }
    public int[] Guests { get; set; }
    public AppliedUsage[] AppliedUsages { get; set; }

}


public class AppliedUsage
{
    public int SoftHoldID { get; set; }
    public int UsageYearID { get; set; }
    public int DaysApplied { get; set; }
    public int PointsApplied { get; set; }
}
```

Issue is: When i called API with above payload then API class parameter-ReservationDraftRequestDto not mapped  AppliedUsages array values.

Please let me know what i need to do map API JSON payload to ReservationDraftRequestDto

Send Request-[image]

Code:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is by design.The binding logic is explicitly excluding arrays while deserializing the json body contents.You could refer to [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/cdeb65faacf04c53845fb76c4b513c9998fc97de/src/WebJobs.Extensions.Http/Utility.cs#L29).

If you want to get the object,here is a simple workaround:

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log)
{
    var reservationDraftRequestDto = req.DeserializeModel<ReservationDraftRequestDto>();

    var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reservationDraftRequestDto);
    //more logic...
    return new OkResult();
}
public static T DeserializeModel<T>(this HttpRequest request)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body))
    using (var textReader = new JsonTextReader(reader))
    {
        request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        });
        return serializer.Deserialize<T>(textReader);
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]